# has DC ever, or will they ever, publish the original ending to Armageddon 2001?

Tags: dc

Armageddon 2001 was a storyline in DC comics in which a hero would go bad, and the identity was a mystery.  When a nine hundred number leaked the information, dc changed the ending, and it upset a lot of fans.

As seen in this link, the original ending to the Armageddon 2001 saga was written, altough not pencilled. 
http://politedissent.com/images/apr08/monarch.html

Was the original ending ever published?  If not, are there any statements from DC that they will ever do so? It will be a 25 year anniversary next year.

Comment: Who knows. Marvel went back and retold Spider-Man's clone saga as it was originally intended to be a few years ago as a stand alone mini series. DC could do the same, or they could revisit the Monarch during the Convergence event.